# Image not showing on page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two pages that both display the same loading image after clicking the submit button. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="/images/stroomschema.png" style="padding: 10px;">
    <form method="post" action="/result" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>1. Selecteer een PDF-print van je rooster.<a href="instruction.html" target="_blank"><img src="/images/questionmark.png" /></a></h3>
        <input type="file" name="infile" id="roosterIn"/>
        <h3>2. Klik op onderstaande knop om het rooster voor te bereiden.</h3>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Selecteer eerst een rooster" id="submitIndex" disabled="disabled" />
    </form
    <img src="/images/loading.gif" style="display: none;" class="loading_image">
    <br>
    <h5><a href={{ logout_url }}>Uitloggen</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#roosterIn').change(function() {
        $('#submitIndex').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#submitIndex').attr('value', 'Volgende')
    })

    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        $('.loading_image').attr('style', 'display: block;')
        $(this).parents('form').hide()
        $(this).parents('form').submit()
    })
</script>
```

The weird thing is that the `.loading_image` image is never showing. If I inspect the page in chrome then it shows the following code:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="/images/stroomschema.png" style="padding: 10px;">
    <form method="post" action="/result" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>1. Selecteer een PDF-print van je rooster.<a href="instruction.html" target="_blank"><img src="/images/questionmark.png" /></a></h3>
        <input type="file" name="infile" id="roosterIn"/>
        <h3>2. Klik op onderstaande knop om het rooster voor te bereiden.</h3>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Selecteer eerst een rooster" id="submitIndex" disabled="disabled" />
    </form
    <br>
    <h5><a href={{ logout_url }}>Uitloggen</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#roosterIn').change(function() {
        $('#submitIndex').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#submitIndex').attr('value', 'Volgende')
    })

    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        $('.loading_image').attr('style', 'display: block;')
        $(this).parents('form').hide()
        $(this).parents('form').submit()
    })
</script>
```

The entire image tag is missing, how is this possible?

Comment: Have you placed your code inside $(document).ready(function(){}); block.

Comment: No, but the faulty code has been identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` tag isn't there because you are missing the closing `>` on your `</form>` tag.

Comment: Oh my, how could I have missed that? My IDE (Aptana3) didn't mark it as wrong, and I must have overlooked it..

Answer (score 0):

change this `</form` to `</form>`